# Creating a Fuzzy Chess Game using Chess Engines

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine, chess, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to *design a Chess Game* that will work based on the *fuzzy logic*. Before making a move, I wanted to compute a **fuzzy evaluation function for each chess piece in each play.** The fuzzy computations are based on the data that are provided in the research paper [Fuzzy Chess Tactics](http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/2532.pdf). I am looking for ***chess engines*** that will provide the fuzzy values for each piece on the board of the given board scenario irrespective of the opponent's or player's. Also I will helpful if somebody can eXplain how the chess engines are selecting a good move [Some brute force algo.. will certainly work though not efficient], I mean based on what criteria ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use the ***MAMDANI-TYPE FUZZY INTERFERENCE*** method to bring FUZZY into action. Also I would suggest to use the Rule Bases and the triangular functions (for the pieces' values) in the research paper http://www.inesc-id.pt/pt/indicadores/Ficheiros/2532.pdf